# MinGW32-make creates incompatible file

Tags: c++, mingw, rcpp, devtools, mingw-w64

So, I am using R, Rtools, and Rcpp to install a package I created.  The problem is that once I compile the library using MinGW32-make and a GNUMakefile, I can't use the library as then Rtools is using i686-w64-mingw32.  And it is saying:

```
c:/rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/RS3/src/build/bin/libs3.dll when searching for -ls3
```

I'm on Windows 7 and 64 bit.  So I am assuming that Rtools uses the 'other' MinGW which is w64(32/64bit) while the MinGW I used was 32-bit only.

Comment: This works for everybody else, and for [win-builder](http://win-builder.r-project.org) so check your setup.

Comment: Rcpp does install correctly, but I'm trying to port a package over from my linux system to windows.  Running Rcpp isn't liking the external library I'm using that I compiled with mingw32.

Comment: You need to *very carefully* read the instructions in the R Inst + Admin manual for Windows, particularly when it comes to Rtools and your PATH settings. You can use external libraries *if compiled with the same gcc/g++ as Rtools uses*.

Comment: After reading a bunch, such as [this comment you made](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rcpp-devel/2014-January/006960.html) and after reviewing RSQLITE it looks like I have a general outline of what I need to do. I need to keep the entire external library within the directory and then create a configure script to compile the library so I can link the .dll.  And doing this makes it use the same compiler both times.

Comment: Oh I see - - it wasn't clear before that you had the sources bundled along so I assumed an external library.   So yes,  RSQLite and RPostreSQL should give you Windows examples.

Comment: I have it installing correctly for when it says `*** arch - i386`, but then it starts over again for `*** arch - x86`.  Then it fails saying the library compiled was incompatible since it was 32 bit.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: I think there are ways to tell `R CMD ...` to disregard the other mode, ie do 32 bit only and not 64 bit, but you will have to check the docs for it as I don't work much on Windows I tend to forget how to do this.